# Whether windows 2012 server SP3 supports SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, windows, support

Please suggest whether windows 2012 server SP3 supports SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** Windows Server 2012 with its Service Packs is supported on a SharePoint Server 2013.

> **Note:**
>
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 is only supported on a SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1 environment.
> - Windows Server 2016 RTM is not supported.

For more details check [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)